# API Manager Publisher Exception when publishing an API

Tags: wso2

I followed the directions as prescribed in http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/User+Roles+in+the+API+Manager
to setup the 'publisher' role.  Unfortunately when I log in as the publisher and try to set the state of the API to 'published' I get an exception where it appears that permissions are not set correctly.  It appears from the screenshots that the documentation is out of date as the screen shots do not match.

What are the correct roles ?

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Error in updating the artifact, artifact id: 75bbe8ef-c0d4-426e-be9b-703468026d9e.Resource update failed. User publisher is not authorized to update the resource /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/creator/ItemService/3.0/api..
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.updateGovernanceArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:457)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.generic.GenericArtifactManager.updateGenericArtifact(GenericArtifactManager.java:181)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateApiArtifact(APIProviderImpl.java:556)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.secure.AuthorizationFailedException: Resource update failed. User publisher is not authorized to update the resource /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/creator/ItemService/3.0/api.
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.update(Repository.java:1084)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.put(Repository.java:288)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:709)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:465)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:657)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.updateGovernanceArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:439)
    ... 66 more
```

Comment: With which user you created the api? Are you trying to change the state of the api by the user different from the user created the api?

Comment: Yes. I followed the directions in the documentation link and created a 'creator' with the role of creator and a 'publisher' with the role of publisher. The creator, created the API, and now I want the publisher to publish it. I've even gone back to update the API with the creator user ( the one who created it ) and I get another exception. `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found: file:/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/creator--ItemService3.0.wsdl
 at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(StringUtils.java:173)
`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a very visual guy and I think if I only had carefully read the document and not relied on the screen shots it would have been OK.  From what I can tell, I properly created the creator role following the text instructions...

```
Configure > Governance and all underlying permissions.
Login
Manage > API > Create
Manage > Resources > Govern and all underlying permissions
```

I had missed the "Manage > Resources > Govern and all underlying permissions"

Once I updated the creator role & re-created my API the publisher could publish the API to the store.